# I cant create table with an ndbcluster engine on ubuntu

Tags: mysql, mysql-cluster

When I try to create a table:
`CREATE TABLE tblCustomer (ID INT) ENGINE=NDBCLUSTER;`

When I show the table status, it is still InnoDB. And when I try to:
`SHOW ENGINES;`
There's no ndbcluster indicated.

[image: Here is the result when I check the version.]

[image: Here is the screenshot of the version of mysql cluster that I'm using.]

Is there something that I'm missing there?
On my data node, I ran `sudo apt-get install mysql-client-core-5.5`

Comment: guys help. do I still need mysql-server/mysql-client for me the run the mysql or the package of mysql-cluster is enough?

Answer (score 0):

Update: I tried setting up VM again without mysql-server and mysql-client and it's working. The mysql-cluster is standalone package.